# Stack to images in an Android application

Tags: android, image, layer

I have tried to find the answer to something I am sure is really simple.  I just want to be able to stack one image ontop of another.  Intent is put a cropped picture of the user's face onto a wacky body.

Answer (score 1):

[Layer List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) is an option. If you need more control I suggest you use a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to draw the wacky body bitmap and then the face.